# How can I transform lines of values for jq to JSON output?

Tags: python, bash, jq

I have this getting the top IPs from my webserver. Trying to return a JSON object seen at the bottom of this. Is there an easy conversion to lines to the format jq needs to create a string array?

```
ips=$(cat /var/log/nginx/access.log | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 5 | cut -d' ' -f8)
```

Results in:

```
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7
```

My expected output is:

```
"192.168.1.2" "192.168.1.3" "192.168.1.5" "192.168.1.6" "192.168.1.7"
```

I may be going about this in a long way. What I have is this output going into a jq for a json file with some other values.

The single values work fine but parsing the list of topipsis where I am having trouble.

```
jq -n --arg stat fails --arg count $count  '[{"stat":$stat,"count": $count},{"liststat": "topips",items: $ARGS.positional }]' --args ${ips[@]}
```

Expected result something like this:

```
{
"topip": ["10.10.20.9","10.10.10.24","10.10.10.26","10.10.10.28","10.10.10.121","192.168.1.152","172.169.10.21","112.10.10.2","10.10.10.21","10.10.10.21"],
"logins":66,
"visits":75,
"errors":1759
}
```

Comment: That jq bit attempts to make an array of objects but your expected output is a single object?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  The connections between the various components of the question sometimes seem rather opaque.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the lines of text in the problem description:

```
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7
```

If count=0, then if you pipe these lines into this variant of your jq program:

```
jq -nR --arg stat fails --arg count $count  '
  [{$stat,$count},
   {liststat: "topips",
    items: [inputs]}]'
```

you would get the output shown below.  You should be able to modify this example in accordance with your requirements. Chances are you could achieve the desired output efficiently using jq alone (i.e., without any of the intermediate steps shown in the Q).

### Output

```
[
  {
    "stat": "fails",
    "count": "0"
  },
  {
    "liststat": "topips",
    "items": [
      "192.168.1.2",
      "192.168.1.3",
      "192.168.1.5",
      "192.168.1.6",
      "192.168.1.7"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would like to be pointed in the direction to skip some steps, it there something I can look up for that? the jq page don't have anything on --args. was alot looking at python as a solution and build from multi-dimension array. my script just needs to parse weblogs for certain things and add to my json so the monitor picks it up and presents in a dashboard.

Comment: This question has been closed. Please either address the issues that have been raised, or ask a new Q. Or read the jq documentation, e.g. the online jq tutorial and manual.